# How can I reinstall a Ubuntu with a configuration from a specific point in time?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cluster, clustering

I am setting up a database cluster on Ubuntu using XtraDB. When I do this I can happily run `apt update && apt upgrade -y` since this is the primordial server configuration.

Now, imagine that I will have to set up a replacement server at a later stage, say a few years from now. If I do the same thing I am bound to end up with different versions of just about everything since the whole idea with Ubuntu (and everything of that same ilk) is that it is continuously being updated. In my case is this probably a bad idea because I will probably end up with incompatible software for the cluster and my replacement node would thus not work.

What is the recommended practice here? How can en ensure that I will be able to create a new machine with an old configuration at a later stage?

Comment: Clone your current machine at the stage you want to keep it, and reinstall it as is? I'm not sure I follow about the state of your DB, because even though its version may change over time, the content, the data, are upkept by you, and won't change with each new version. The OS you run your DB system on is of little importance, here, aside from compatibility issues. You can export your DB content and reinject it in a new DB system with little to no corruption, and just the need to (maybe) compact it after reinjection.

Comment: You can also keep your OS up-to-date, and run your DB in an ad-hoc virtual machine, based on an OS you'll only maintain for security purposes (updates), without adding new functionalities (no upgrades). A lot of commercial DB systems rely on that kind of setup.

Comment: @Didier, the problem is XtraDB since that is, ideally, a cluster of identical servers. The content of the DB is not the concern here, but the possible problem of creating a new node at a later stage. Your second idea is very interesting and I will look into that; I could possibly run each node as a Docker image with my software setup static. Thanks.